# Is it possible to change the begin position of a vector in C++ to clear its first n elements?

Tags: c++, list, vector

Say I have a vector of integers [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. As far as I always understood the vector has a memory adress @v and then if we want to access an element i we just need to do @v+i*size_of_element. Perhaps I'm wrong and std::vector is implemented in a different way.

If I want to delete the first 4 elements and end up with [5,6,7], wouldn't I just need to update @v and clear the elements, in this case they're just integers so I'm assuming it would be O(1).

Is my assumption wrong and is there any way I can achieve this in C++ using vector, that is, updating the adress of start of the vector to "clear" the first n elements?

If no, would it be possible using std::list?

Comment: There are no vectors in C and your title explicitely mentions C++. Both are very different languages. Please do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: "Perhaps I'm wrong and std::vector is implemented in a different way" no matter how the vector is implemented, you should not mess around with implementation details, but rather use its public API, did you browse [some reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to see what methods it offers?

Comment: You're talking in the abstract about `@v`. Things would be a lot clearer if you showed real code. That would also clarify what you mean by "updating @v". There's `std::vector::erase()`, but that doesn't update `std::vector::data()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible in theory, and some other languages have an operation like this on arrays (*slices* in Go and Rust come to mind). However, `std::vector` does not offer such a feature, per se.

Regardless of the language, the elements that you "deleted" are never really gone from memory, because the memory is still allocated; at best, you can get a "view" on the underlying array that omits a number of elements at the start or end.

The C++ way to get such a "view" is to use a pair of iterators. For example, `my_vector.begin() + 4`, `my_vector.end()` represents all elements except the first 4 (assuming there are at least 4). All the `std` algorithms that operate on ranges accept iterator pairs, which makes this a useful representation.

`std::list` does allow you to really delete a number of elements from the front, but the operation is O(*n*) where *n* is the number of dropped elements. This is because each element needs to be traversed and freed individually.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You  can easily construct another vector from the first like this:

```
vector<int> newOne(old.begin()+4,old.end());
```

Comment: This operation will copy the other vector though, right?

Comment: Yes, but depending on the content of the vector it may be not so costly... And that's all you can do reliably. You may do tricky things accessing `data` but that will be *tricky*.